# What is the complexity of Gradient descent given sparsity $s$, condition number $k$ and size of the matrix $N$?

Tags: optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, gradient-descent

Given the Linear system

$$Ax = b$$

where $A$ is an $s$-sparse ($s$ is the maximum number of non-zero entries in $A$), $k$-conditioned ($k$ is the ratio between the highest and the smallest eigenvalue) matrix of size $N$, how can I express the time complexity of CG method based on those three parameters? 
I have found out different questions in Stack exchange ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607423/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-conjugate-gradient-method),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802057/computational-complexity-of-conjugate-gradient-method-for-a-positive-semidefinit)), but none of them considers all three parameters.

Comment: CG is a method for systems of equations in which $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.  Is your $A$ matrix symmetric and positive definite?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, my matrix is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the first question you linked to, which correctly answers that it is $O(m \sqrt{\kappa})$.  There's no direct dependence on $N$ but since $m>N$, this is dealt with.

Comment: How can it be m > N? m should be equal or lower than N. In the worst case the matrix is full then m=N, no?

Comment: If the matrix is of size $N$ by $N$, then in order for it to be positive definite, $m$ must be greater than or equal to $N$ (all diagonal entries must be nonzero.)  The matrix is full when $m=N^{2}$.